# Designing a simple GUI framework in C

Tags: c, user-interface, design-patterns

I need to design, for a school project, **a very simple** GUI framework which needs to support the following controls/widgets: Window, Panel, Image, Label and Button.

- The first question that came up to my mind is whether or not `Window` should be a control. I think it suppose to.
- We have `Window` and `Panel` which can contain other controls. `Button`, `Label` and `Image`, cannot. So we need two basic types of controls; One which is a container and another which is not (I've seen that in Gtk implementation the later is also a container, but can only contain one single child. It's called [GtkBin](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBin.html). I think it's an overhead for my simple project.
- Third issue I came across with is: I need to **traverse the UI tree** (for the drawing) but since there's no mechanism for polymorphism in C, it's becoming somewhat problematic.

I thought about the following solution, utilizing `union`. Basically I'll need some function to convert a generic `Control` to it's actuall type.

```
typedef struct button {
    char *image_path;
} Button;

typedef struct control_node {
    Control *node;
    struct control_node *next;
} ControlNode;

typedef struct panel {
    ControlNode *children;
} Panel;

typedef union control_data {
    Panel panel;
    Button button;
} ControlData;

typedef struct control {
    int x;
    int y;
    int type;
    ControlData *data;
} Control;
```

So I'd like to get your thoughts about the issues I've introduced and an opinion about my current strategy (I am **NOT** looking for an implementation, rather thoughts/ideas etc)

Thanks.

Comment: Rather than a tagged union, you can achieve polymorphism by making your own vTables.

Comment: C is not really the best tool to reinvent the GUI wheel with... GUI can massively benefit from OOP, and faking those features in C is mighty tedious.

Comment: he probably meant to say that you're reinventing the wheel

Comment: "I need to design a very simple GUI framework"... no you don't. If you would, you'd know how. Since you don't know how, you need to *find* a GUI framework.

Comment: Guys, it's a school project and this demand is part of the requirements.

Comment: @RonErikson: Ah. School. Source of dumb requirements and restrictions since the invention of the wheel. ;-)  Sorry. ;-)

Comment: @RonErikson - knock yourself out: http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf

Comment: @Quentin I wouldn't say English grammar is a reliable indicator of programming skill. Feel free to look up and address the author to suggest edits :) Way to judge a book by its cover, figuratively and almost literally ;)

Comment: @ddriver Yeah, that comment was decidedly useless. The content looks solid. Still, ouch :p

Comment: ^^^ what @ddriver says.  The OS API may be C but, for GUI framework, you need to inerface to an OO language ASAP.

Comment: @MartinJames OP must do this with plain C.

Comment: Indeed, it should be plain C (C99 to be presice). I wouldn't like to go all the way through with "OOC"  since I don't have the time and efforts for this and it seems to me like a huge overhead. Is there an in-between solution?

Comment: @RonErikson - the overhead is neither huge, nor avoidable. It is the one single correct approach to this problem. For your 5 UI elements I'd say it shouldn't take you more than an hour, and I take under consideration that you are a student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put a `void *` first thing in the layout of every "GUI class" that will point to manually implemented v-tables for every type. The first function in every type's v-table could be one, returning a unique integer for every type (or just be a unique integer), so you can tell what is what and have some type safety implemented. Although it is not necessary, you could use the v-table pointer value to determine the type (since it will be unique), which will save on memory, but will be a little less obvious. It is also crucial to have virtualism in the object destruction, so a destructor function for handling each unique type's internals with its position in the v-table being consistent is also a must. Although for your task this might actually be avoidable, but for production it is a must.

As for the actual tree, this should be built on a simple parent-child relation, revolving around a leaf and node interface, the leaf only holding a pointer to the parent, the node also including a dynamic list type you must also implement. Then traversing the tree is fairly straightforward.

You can modularize a bit by using "interfaces" structs and aggregation in lieu of inheritance, but it won't save you much effort compared to implementing every type on its own, as long as you keep the v-table pointer the first object in the type layout, so that you know what you are working with and how to use it. The layout of the rest is not that crucial to follow any guidelines, as long as you know the type and cast the pointer to the appropriate struct type. But since every object will have a parent, even the root, which will be identifiable by its parent being 0, you really should put the parent second after the v-table pointer, this way you can avoid casting when all you need to access is the parent.

Another thing you can benefit from is using signals, as in have another pointer in every button, so you can assign it to a function to be executed when you "click" the button.

Comment: lol 'implement C++'.  Your answer is good enough for an upvote, but I would not want to do it:)

Comment: @MartinJames - can you think of any other way to achieve some degree of uniformity? It is not really implementing C++, just a tiny tiny subset of critically needed features :) It is actually doable, and frequently used in production grade C code.

Comment: 'can you think of any other way' no, I cannot:).   It's the way I would do it if I was, say, sitting at a keyboard with a gun to my head and being forced to write a GUI in C.   Your answer is good in the sense that it's the least bad solution:)

Comment: I find that alarmingly often teachers give ridiculous assignments, almost like they don't really have a clear idea what exactly are they making the students do. My bet is that's a case of people with poor programing skills, who couldn't find a job, but are still "ahead enough" to "teach", even if not really good teachers. As a saying goes "those who cannot do teach", which often explains a lot of "learning gone wrong". In school our "information technologies" teacher didn't knew 1% of what I knew, and I am self taught.

Comment: @Quentin - chances are your teacher might expect something a lot more simple, and be trumped by the fact you went on to implement OOP features.

Comment: @ddriver I wouldn't deny that some teachers are alarmingly incompetent, but I don't believe it's the case here. In fact, this assignment seems to have a lot more learning value and be *a lot* more interesting than most C assignment I've seen. If it's a 6-month project, that is.

Comment: The OP has a chance, (given sufficient time, as you say).  S/he does seem to have thought about some of the problems, understands that some controls can be containers, some controls can take focus while others cannot.  A chance, but it would need to be good odds for me to put cash down:)

Comment: @Quentin - for me it was very interesting to understand how OOP works in "C idioms", and I really hate using anything which I don't understand how it works, at least basically. Not a big fan of "it works by magic" :)

Comment: @ddriver well I'm struggling with MFC event routing shenanigans right now, and I'm about to go berserk for exactly that reason.

Comment: @Quentin I wouldn't touch MFC with a stick... I've had my share of similar problems with Qt though, even if it is a lot more sane.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different problems here: the conception of the GUI and its implementation in C. If conception is simpler in OO model, just write it that way. As first C++ compiler were just preprocessors for C code, C **can** implement OO modeling with the use of vtables.

First define clearly what are your objects (classes): which can be containers, which are drawables, which can react to mouse or keyboard events. What are their properties: text, x-y coordinates, bitmaps, and probably a z-coordinate. At the end of that phase, you should have a hierachy of classes with properties and methods, and possible overrides  in subclasses - if you have learned it, UML could help for that part.

Second, you will have to implement that in C. Don't worry about it. You will not have the syntactic sugar of copy and move constructors for free, nor the notion of public, private and protected attributes, but `struct` can contain sub-objects, pointers to other structs and pointer to functions.

You just need a lexicon to translate OO tools in C :

- class: struct
- field of class: field of struct
- method of class: function whose first attribute is a pointer to an instance of the struct
- virtual method : pointer to a method
- constructor and destructor : special methods that must be called explicitely - no automatic destruction if a struct goes out of scope

A non final class (contains virtual methods) should contain a VTABLE, which is a mere array of pointers to the virtual methods. This VTABLE should be first element of struct to ease class pointer casting. A derived class first contains its own vtable (if it is not final), then its attributes and then an instance of its parent. A cast from parent to derived pointer is just a matter of adding an offset. If you need multiple inheritance, you add the other parents after the first in the struct. Virtual inheritance would be slightly  tougher to implement because it involves pointers in the VTABLE. Same if you need class aware objects, just add a constant in the VTABLE. But I do not think that you need all that for your requirement.

So look twice if you really want the harder bits: multiple inheritance and class aware objects, then just implement each class in its .h + .c file. You even get for free private methods: they are just static functions.

Comment: It is not clear if that GUI is actually going to be drawn, I was thinking it was more of a GUIs logic skeleton. If it indeed needs to be drawn, then the OOP features are the last concern when it comes to complexity and implementation time.

Comment: ^^ sounds like a line from 'The Impossible Dream':  "To draw the undrawable GUI..."

Comment: @MartinJames - my GUI classes are not bound to any particular representation, this way I can throw them at different APIs which should handle each object appropriately. It describes structure and function, but not style, this way it can work everywhere, from hardware accelerated graphics to text mode console :) I also consider porting it to Braille.